# Where can I find a Dremora Markynaz?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently obtained the Dead Thrall spell and have determined that the best choice for my Thrall, barring killing one of the unique people that can't actually be killed..., is probably the Dremora Markynaz. Being that their max level is just under the max 40 for the spell. I'm having a bit of trouble locating where any might SPAWN however. Does anyone know where they might be?

Comment: Since [Markynaz are a levelled spawn](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dremora#Melee_Fighters), your own level must be around the right range to have any chance to find them. Are you somewhere around level 36?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dremora Markynaz is a [Level 36 Dremora](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aDremora#Dremora_Types).

Problem is: Dremora are rare in Skyrim, and they are levelled. There are some in the [Shrine of Mehrunes Dagon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shrine_of_Mehrunes_Dagon) and  [Shalidor's Maze](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shalidor's_Maze).

Now, due to the [Respawning](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning) mechanics, it is likely that the few areas that do contain Dremora are fixed to levels that are way below the required level for a Dremora Markynaz to spawn (both are available rather early -- Labyrinthian - and by extension the Maze - is often an early target, and the Shrine belongs to a 20+ daedric quest).

That said ...
On PC, you can use [Console commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to spawn Markynaz via `placeatme <ID>`. Replace `<ID>` by the respective ID from the Dremora list, and there you go.

There might also be a way to reset the level of a location via a command (`resetinterior <cellid>` looks promising but I can't verify that at this point).

Comment: Meaning that at lvl 60... I'm pretty much not gonna find one then, bugger.

Comment: I revoke former comment, the two inside Mehrune's shrine are always WAY under-leveled, even now they're only Kynval.

Comment: @Selonianth Is that one of the things fixed by the Unofficial Skyrim patch? (I know it fixes follower not-leveling)

Comment: @RavenDreamer no idea. I don't have a PC so therefore I don't have the Unnofficial Skyrim patch. But I don't mean that the dungeon doesn't level with me, it's rather that compared to the two blokes outside, Valkynaz I believe, they are roughly... well a hell of a lot easier to kill. At all times. I expect that if I hit level 70 or so without finding a favorite Dead Thrall they will be Markynaz for me.